# How can I export the XML file structure into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xml

The structure of the code is as shown below:

This is an xml file

```xml
<ROOT>
    <data>
        <record>
            <field name="Country or Area">Afghanistan</field>
            <field name="Year">2020</field>
            <field name="Item">Gross Domestic Product (GDP)</field>
            <field name="Value">508.453721937094</field>
        </record>
        <record>
            <field name="Country or Area">Afghanistan</field>
            <field name="Year">2019</field>
            <field name="Item">Gross Domestic Product (GDP)</field>
            <field name="Value">496.940552822825</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</ROOT>
```

I have tried, i've tried other methods but no luck

```py
from lxml import objectify

xml = objectify.parse('GDP_pc.xml')
root = xml.getroot()

data=[]
for i in range(len(root.getchildren())):
    data.append([child.text for child in root.getchildren()[i].getchildren()])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['Country or Area', 'Year', 'Item', 'Value',]
```

Comment: I was having issues with the data downloaded as xml from:

http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=SNAAMA&f=grID%3a101%3bcurrID%3aUSD%3bpcFlag%3a1

I re-downloaded it as a csv file and the problems went away.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the pandas method `pd.read_xml()`?

It reads and transform a xml file into a `dataframe`.

Just to the following:

```py
df = pd.read_xml('GDP_pc.xml')
```

You can read more about it on the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html)

Comment: I have but it doesn't show much.  the data is below downloaded ans xml

http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=SNAAMA&f=grID%3a101%3bcurrID%3aUSD%3bpcFlag%3a1

Comment: Oh, could you clarify more the problem on your answer then? It might get easier for us to help you. What is the problem occuring when you use readl_xml( )?

Comment: Also, `read_xml` allows you to change the `xpath` to match your needs. This should do: `pd.read_xml('GDP_pc.xml', xpath='.//record", names=['Country or Area', 'Year', 'Item', 'Value'])` where `names` allows to you to rename same named nodes like `<field>`.

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 0 entries
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   record  0 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 0.0+ bytes
record
record

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<ROOT>
    <data>
        <record>
             <field name="Country or Area">Afghanistan</field>
            <field name="Year">2020</field>
            <field name="Item">Gross Domestic Product (GDP)</field>
            <field name="Value">508.453721937094</field>
        </record>
         <record>
            <field name="Country or Area">Afghanistan</field>
             <field name="Year">2019</field>
             <field name="Item">Gross Domestic Product (GDP)</field>
             <field name="Value">496.940552822825</field>
         </record>
      </data> 
</ROOT>'''

data = []
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for rec in root.findall('.//record'):
    data.append({field.attrib['name']: field.text for field in rec.findall('field')})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
Country or Area  Year                          Item             Value
0     Afghanistan  2020  Gross Domestic Product (GDP)  508.453721937094
1     Afghanistan  2019  Gross Domestic Product (GDP)  496.940552822825
```

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 10
      6 xml = ET.parse('GDP_pc.xml') 
      9 data = []
---> 10 root = ET.fromstring(xml)
     11 for rec in root.findall('.//record'):
 

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\school\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py:1342, in XML(text, parser)
   1340 if not parser:
   1341     parser = XMLParser(target=TreeBuilder())
-> 1342 parser.feed(text)
   1343 return parser.close()

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'ElementTree'

Comment: When you copy and paste the code in the answer - does it work?